# Output figure size in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just upgraded my Jupyter version to 4.2.1 and it seems as though inline figures have gotten a lot larger for the same `figsize`.

Am I imagining this?

Can I change that without changing the `figsize`?

Comment: from which version have you upgraded?

Comment: Not sure... I think I have not upgraded my setup for at least 7 or 8 months. I tend to do that if I am in the middle of a big project.

Answer (score 19):

You can use top-level `matplotlib` settings like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,10)
```

This will change default figure size to 10x10. More on that in the documentation: http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: I think you are missing my point. The default figsize was and still is 8 by 6 inches. The display size of the figure is much larger now than with previous versions. I think it has something to do with the CSS of the notebook template that has changed.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I must've blanked out (sleep deprivation?), now I see that your question is completely different.

Answer (score 9):

The scaling of the figure for figures with `%matplotlib inline` depends on the `figure.dpi` parameter. So if your figures are to small and you do not want to increase the `figsize` then you can just set

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150 # default for me was 75
```

I also had the impression that the scaling changed at some point, but I guess this can also appear if you change your screen/resolution.